# Fosuserebundle: admin creates users. Don't want to login after register

Tags: authentication, admin, fosuserbundle, registration

In my program, there will be an admin or superadmin who will create the rest of the users. The problem is that when using Fosuserbundle to register a user, it automatically logs in. 
I don't want to log in with the new user, but I need the new users id to show another form with extra data about the user.

Any help??

This is what I have in my controller:

```
 public function crearusuarioAction(Request $request, $idCentro)
    {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(
'fos_user_registration_register'
));
    }
```

and in the Registrationcontroller of the bundle I have:

```
 public function confirmedAction()
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }
    $idUsuario = $user->getId();
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(
          'crearUsuarioRegistrado',
      array('idUsuario' => $idUsuario)
    ));
}
```